# React native Fixed header / footer iphone X

Tags: iphone, react-native, react-native-ios

As a personal project to learn ReactNative, i am building an instagram like app (Fixed header, footer and scrollable content section). What would be a best practice to make this kind of layout?

The problem is that, in iPhone X this doesn't work quite well. If I use the  `SafeAreaView` component i can get the Header section to work, but then I lose the ability to correctly position the footer. By using the following code:

```
render() {
    const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
    return (
      <View style={[{backgroundColor: '#F00'}]}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#AFD', height: 50}}>
          <Text>Head</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#DFC', height: height-100}}>
          <Text>Body</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#CDF', height: 50}}>
          <Text>Toes</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I get:

[image: iphone X without SafeAreaView]

If I use the `SafeAreaView` component, it gets a bit better for the header but the footer loses the reference completely:

```
  <SafeAreaView style={[{backgroundColor: '#F00'}]}>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#AFD', height: 50}}>
      <Text>Head</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#DFC', height: height-100}}>
      <Text>Body</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#CDF', height: 50}}>
      <Text>Footer</Text>
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
```

[image: Using SafeAreaView fixes the header but loses the footer]

My last option was then to use the `SafeAreaView` for the header part, which then makes the header too small (the content gets clipped if i don't account for the extra height, which doesn't help so much)

```
  <View style={[{backgroundColor: '#F00'}]}>
    <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: '#AFD', height: 50}}>
      <Text>Head</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#DFC', height: height-100}}>
      <Text>Body</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#CDF', height: 50}}>
      <Text>Footer</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
```

[image: Using SafeAreaView for the header]

So, what would be a best practice to achieve this layout? Also, is there any good resources for layouts in ReactNative besides the documentation?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use https://github.com/miyabi/react-native-safe-area module. It's very easy to use and works as per requirement. Works well on different iOS versions, automatically adjusts on orientation change. You just have to `addEventListener` and all will be handled automatically.

Follow instructions from https://github.com/miyabi/react-native-safe-area#installation